# Spring @Autowired not working , bean is null

Tags: spring, autowired

I am using spring 5.2.8

I am using @Autowired to get create the Bean. But i am getting NullPointer when I used this bean

configuration

```
@Configuration
@Primary
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.try.appli"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.tryappli.persistence")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class AppliConfiguration {

...
```

My component in package com.try.appli

```
@Component
@Primary
public class Mycomponent extends MycomponentAbstract {


    @Autowired
    MyService service 

     public handle()
        String data ="{data to update}";
        service.update(data);
```

service :

```
@Service
public MyService {

    @Autowired
    private RestOperations resoperation;

    public void update(dataToUpdate) {
        restOperations.put("url", dataToUpdate);
    }
....
```

I also tried to put the annotation on the implementation but without success

In web.xml

```
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

Comment: Scattering random snippets is not helpful, here, and we can't reproduce this. Could you show us how you create a context? also, what you mean in "i am getting NullPointer when I used this bean"? you can't fetch that bean from the context? or you can't inject IN it? or it doesn't get injected in some @Service layer class? please provide more information.

Comment: Your bean must be in Spring Context, otherwise it is null, please add your Context creation

Comment: @configuration = context creation no ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my Spring @Autowired field null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null)

Comment: @Roland Weisleder   I don't use new service;